# Is it possible to obfuscate groovy codebase using progaurd?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, proguard, obfuscation

I have a groovy code that uses a lot of dynamicity and run-time closer classes. The Progaurd obfuscation works but at run time it fails on a method calling with an error "Missing method exception"

I tried keeping the classes but it is written in a very tightly coupled manner so in keeping those, I ended up exposing all the vital information.

Any help or clue is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Groovy is a dynamic language, the project code uses lots of closure and run time classes so obfuscation is failing at runtime. Finally, I come to the conclusion that not to go for obfuscation. Compile static was one option but unable to exclude closures.